# XML Element and Type hierarchies

Tags: xml, types, vocabulary, nomenclature

I have a conceptual question, because I'm currently writing a concept concerning Dataexchange using xml & xsds.

When describing xsds, I often find myself wondering whether I am using the correct vocabulary. If I have, for example a definition as follows in my xsd:

```
<xs:complexType name="choiceOfKnownDateType">
 <xs:choice>
  <xs:element name="yearMonthDay" type="completeDate"/>
  <xs:element name="yearMonth" type="yearMonthOnly"/>
  <xs:element name="year" type="yearOnly"/>
 </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Am I correctly describing that example as:
"We have a complex TYPE consisting of the ELEMENTS yearMonthDay, yearMonth and year. These ELEMENTS are of the TYPE completeDate, yearMonthOnly and yearOnly."

I don't care about the correctness or improvements over the example (I just made it up), I just need to know, whether I am using the terms "Element" and "Type" correctly :)

Thanks a lot in advance

Mischa

Comment: An a fairly informal level, your terminology is fine. A pedant, however, would tell you that a type does not consist of elements. Rather, a type defines a content model, which in your case is a choice, and the choice contains a number of particles, which in this case are element particles, and each element particle refers to an element declaration, and the element declarations are named yearMonthDay, yearMonth, and year.

Comment: thanks Michael, that was the 'pedantic' answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the example is an `xs:choice` rather than a sequence it would be more correct to say that the type allows "exactly one child element, which may be either `yearMonthDay` (of the type `completeDate`), `yearMonth` (of the type `yearMonthOnly`) or `year` (of the type `yearOnly`)".